# Как отдельно вывести способы доставки woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева я вывел способы доставки кодом

```
    <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Ниже я вывел способы оплаты кодом

```
 <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) :
                    $WC_Payment_Gateways = new WC_Payment_Gateways();
                    $available_gateways = $WC_Payment_Gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
                    if ( ! empty( $available_gateways ) ) {
                        $count=0;
                        foreach ( $available_gateways as $gateway ) {
                            $count++; ?>

                            <div class="item wc_payment_method payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>">

                                <div class="checkbox-form">
                                    <input type="radio" id="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( $gateway->chosen, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" style="display: none;">
                                    <label class="label" for="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" class="d-flex">
                                        <h4 class="item-title"><?php echo $gateway->get_title(); /* phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped */ ?></h4>

                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php }
                    } ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

В чем вопрос.
Справа выведена таблица кодом

```
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
```

В этой таблице работает ajax и в ней тоже есть способы доставки и оплаты.
Получается у меня 2 раза повторяются 2 одинаковые формы с одинаковыми id radio инпутов и т.д.
Тыкая слева на инпут, выделается инпут который нахаодится справа в таблице.

Короче, нужно либо как-то убрать формы доставки и оплаты справа,вообще из кода.. только как? не понимаю где редактировать эту страницу. Но оставить цену и кнопку отправки формы и при этом чтобы по всей форме работал ajax...

Либо скрыть повторяющиеся формы которые справа (при помощи css) и сделать как-то чтоб radio инпуты в формах слева выделялись и обновлялись при помощи ajax

Answer (score 0):

Найдите файл review-order.php  в шаблонах,за вывод методов доставки отвечает хук

```
 <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
```

Удалите его из шаблона и все

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как внедрить вашкод в тему wodmart